# aiogram бот не отправляет видео в mediagroup

Tags: python, aiogram

Пишу бота, который будет отправлять пачки фото и видео с папки, медиагруппу из фото он отправляет, но как только переходит момент к mp4 файлам, он просто их игнорирует. Пробовал отправлять через InputFile - он не отправлял вообще видео, через open(file, 'rb') - отправлял только одно.

```
from aiogram.types.input_file import InputFile
from aiogram.types import MediaGroup
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

async def sendmedia(message):
    files = [file for file in listdir('1/') if isfile(join('1/', file))] # ['pic  (1).jpg', 'pic  (10).jpg', 'pic  (11).jpg', 'pic  (12).jpg', 'pic  (13).jpg', 'pic  (14).jpg', 'pic  (15).jpg', 'pic  (16).jpg', 'pic  (17).jpg', 'pic  (18).jpg', 'pic  (19).jpg', 'pic  (2).jpg', 'pic  (20).jpg', 'pic  (21).jpg', 'pic  (22).jpg', 'pic  (23).jpg', 'pic  (24).jpg', 'pic  (25).jpg', 'pic  (26).jpg', 'pic  (27).jpg', 'pic  (28).jpg', 'pic  (29).jpg', 'pic  (3).jpg', 'pic  (4).jpg', 'pic  (5).jpg', 'pic  (6).jpg', 'pic  (7).jpg', 'pic  (8).jpg', 'pic  (9).jpg', 'video  (1).mp4', 'video  (2).mp4', 'video  (3).mp4', 'video  (4).mp4', 'video  (5).mp4', 'video  (6).mp4', 'video  (7).mp4']
    i = -1
    media = MediaGroup()
    for file in files:
        i += 1
        pic = file.endswith('.jpg') or file.endswith('.png') # True, если файл является фотографией
        if i != 10: # проверка, превышает ли MediaGroup лимит в 10 вложений
            if pic == True:
                media.attach_photo(InputFile(f'1/{file}'))
            else:
                media.attach_video(open(f'1/{file}', 'rb'))
        else:
            i = 0
            await bot.send_media_group(
                chat_id = message.chat.id,
                media=media
            )
            media = MediaGroup()
            if pic == True:
                media.attach_photo(InputFile(f'1/{file}'))
            else:
                media.attach_video(open(f'1/{file}', 'rb'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы прослушивать все виды сообщений, достаточно определить content_type как

```
dispatcher.register_message_handler(self.on_msg, content_type=aiogram.types.ContentType.all())
```